# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how do I follow a link that opens a new window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a link that opens in a new window, and I need to test the part of my app that is within that new window.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just validate that the link has it's target set to _blank?

Comment: no, cause I need to run tests on the stuff that the link points too... actually... I think I can pull that information with x_path.. thanks for helping think!

Comment: Ah, you should just be able to say "Then I follow the link 'login'"

Answer (score 15):

Define a step that contains this code:

page.driver.browser.switch_to.window (page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)

switch_to is a selenium command that allows you to change over to a new window
window_handles returns a list of currently open windows

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old post, but here's a Cucumber step definition using Capybara and the Poltergeist driver:

```
And /^I follow "([^"]*)" to the new window$/ do |link|
  new_window = window_opened_by { click_link link }
  switch_to_window new_window
end
```