# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how do I test if a link opens in a new window / tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a preview link in my app, and it opens in a new window, so that you don't lose any unsaved changes... how do a divert cucumber's attention to the new window?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, he did http://stackoverflow.com/a/7030745/535406

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "url.com/", target: "_blank" do %>
<%= image_tag 'images/image.png', class: "image_class" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

When I have links that open a new window/tab, I usually configure it to open on the same window for the test environment. I created this method on my application helper:

```
def link_target
  %[target="#{Rails.env.test? ? "_self" : "_blank"}"]
end
```

And inside my markup:

```
<a href="/path" <%= link_target %>>Click here</a>
```